# What do you call it when you ask a question but you actually know the answer?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

And you may not really expect an answer or want/need an answer. Not quite rhetorical.
For example you may be talking about something that happened and wondering who did it and everyone knows who did it including yourself but you ask, 'I wonder who that was.'

Comment: Why do you have to wonder who did it when you know who did it?

Comment: @Nagarajan Shanmuganathan You're not wondering who it was. You're stirring things, using a common strategy.

Comment: As in it was unintentional? Like you did not intend on a rhetorical question? I would call that an _impulsive statement (question)_.

Comment: Or as in you are _interested_ in an answer you already have?

Comment: Or as in _interested_ not in means to find an answer, but to start a conversation about it? possibly _inquisitive_?

Comment: I am just ranting things, because like everyone else, I have no idea why you would be interested in an answer you already have. what do you seek to gain with this answer?

Comment: This is exactly what a rhetorical question is. It is a question asked to make a point. It doesn't matter whether you go on to provide the answer explicitly or not -- although that is also a type of rhetorical question, providing a pretext to explain.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Er...you are taking my name in vain. Is that allowed? Do the malcontents and smartguys approve?

Comment: @PeterPoint Thanks for proving my ... er... point.

Comment: You don't seem to have been interacting with the questions posed. Perhaps you already know your own answer :) . In any case, if you are certain it's not a *rhetorical question*, please [edit] your question to explain why. Explaining the reason(s) for asking "I wonder who ..." would be a good start. In the mean time, I'm voting to place this question on hold as being unclear.

Comment: I fix people's grammar all over the internet, and this sub SE is still always on the border of annoying me.

Answer (score 5):

A question where one does not want or need anyone to supply an answer **is** a rhetorical question.

The rhetorical device is either for the question to make its own point, because the question is left hanging for its hearers to consider, or to provide a pretext for its asker to answer it and make his point with that statement.

> The rhetorical question is usually defined as any question asked for a purpose other than to obtain the information the question asks.
>
> Gideon O. Burton, *Silva Rhetoricae,* Brigham Young University. [Rhetorical questions](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/R/rhetorical%20questions.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your motive for asking...

Perhaps ***Machiavellian*** - practising, or characterised by, (esp. political) expediency in preference to morality; unscrupulous, duplicitous; astute, cunning, scheming (OED).

Answer (score 0):

One who is doing this is probably ***testing the water***; perhaps they are just itching to name *you-know-who* (as an example) but hesitant and looking for (potential) supporters before they are seen as voicing their opinion openly. If someone else falls for it and opens up, they then can just second them (with the confidence that they are not the *first* to face the *consequences*, if any).

ODO:

> **[test the water](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/test)**: Judge people's feelings or opinions before taking further action.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a

*"Who's buried in Grant's tomb" question*

You can also react to the question, after you or someone else has asked it, by saying

*Duh!*

to show that you just realized the answer was obvious.  This is a fairly recent thing, and it might just be for the U.S., I'm not sure.

"Duh!" is usually said with a certain musical inflection in the voice, and may be accompanied by a heel of the hand tap to the temple.  Optional variant:

*Well, duh!*

**Edit:** one more -- a *vapid* question

(offering nothing that is stimulating or challenging)